# unable to point different two domains (virtual host) in wamp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, wamp, wampserver

in wamp setup, i am unable to set virtual host for my application.

Appache;
D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.8\conf\extra

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/"
ServerName www.example.org
# ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www/facebook_post_style
ServerName www.example.net
ServerAlias *.example.net
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

in host

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1        www.example.org
127.0.0.1        www.example.net
```

I did above configuration. For both domain, same output is displaying.

please check this below URL.[image]

Comment: yes, i added that also. i updated my post @raina77ow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\facebook_post_style"
ServerName www.example.net
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\FolderName"
ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

also make sure you have uncommented the following line from httpd.conf file

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

check this  [article](http://cesaric.com/?p=255) for details

Comment: should i add any details in system32 host file

Comment: doing like below may be over riding. 127.0.0.1       www.example.net
127.0.0.1 www.example.org

Comment: I just checked my setting, I have changed my answer from 127.0.0.1 to *:80

Answer (score 0):

With below stuff virtual host worked Apache;

> D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.8\conf\extra

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost
#DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host.localhost"
DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/"
ServerName localhost
#ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.localhost-access.log" common
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
   # DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host2.localhost"
   DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/facebook_post_style"
    ServerName localhost1
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
   # DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host2.localhost"
   DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/crop"
    ServerName www.example.net
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

in host:

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost1
127.0.0.1   www.example.net
```

click on the wamp icon in task bar > Apache > httpd.conf

enable below line

## Virtual hosts

> Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf